# Oldstyle numerals or lining numerals with units of measurement?

Tags: typography, siunitx, oldstylenums, units

What is considered proper typography regarding which set of numerals to use with units of measurement?

A real-life example:

> In the experiment, shown schematically in figure 2.2, we illuminate an array of 10 slits, each 50 nm wide, with a laser beam at λ = 830 nm.

Which numerals in the above sentence should be set as oldstyle (text) numerals and which should be lining numerals? As far as I know,

- "figure 2.2" should be oldstyle in any case.
- "10 slits" should also be oldstyle.
- for "50 nm wide", a case could be made for either one. Personally I think oldstyle looks better here.
- for "λ = 830 nm", the answer should be the same as "50 nm wide". But this is even more of a grey area, since strictly speaking the "830 nm" is part of an equation. If it were "f/2 = 50 Hz" then I would definitely want the "2" to be a lining numeral.

Also, is using the `siunitx` package macros for every instance of a number followed by a unit of measurement the best way to achieve this?

**ADDENDUM**

Unfortunately using `siunitx` gives me the dreaded `Too many math alphabets` error and I'm not wasting any more precious hours of my life fixing *that* one. Here are the macros that have always worked well enough for me:

```
\newcommand{\unit}[1]{\mbox{$\;\mathrm{#1}$}}
\newcommand{\micron}{\mbox{$\;\text{\textmu m}$}} % special case of \unit
```

Comment: Be consistent. If you use lining numerals before *one* unit of measure, then *all* should be lining. And I'd prefer "an array of ten slits".

Comment: As I came across [Don't ask us about best practices, glom of nit, or Mrs Cake](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1246/18674) quite parallel to reading your question, I had to smile.

Comment: Related: [Using text figures in technical and scientific documents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12400)

Comment: @BenediktBauer I looked at that post to try to determine whether this question was appropriate. But it's one of the most confusing meta questions I've ever seen. For one thing, I'm not a Discworld buff so I had to google "glom of nit" and "Mrs Cake", and even now I have no idea why we can't ask about them. The only thing I got out of it was to solicit advice rather than ask about best practices, which I tried to do in the above question.

Comment: @ptomato To me it still looked like a best practices question. While I was thinking about this comment here, there came a simple and interesting trick into my mind, which should very easily allow to check if the question comes close to a best practices question: If can sum up your question as "I want to achieve *x* by means of *y* (maybe additional "because of *z*"), how do I get this?" then it is quite surely not a best practices question.

Comment: @ptomato: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: @Silex, I realize that. I'm still hoping others will weigh in.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to set any numbers with units as maths, leading to something like:

```
In the experiment, shown schematically in figure 2.2, we illuminate an array of 10 slits,
each $50~\mathrm{nm}$ wide, with a laser beam at $\lambda = 830~\mathrm{nm}$.
```

[image: math]

It makes things consistent: you shouldn't use old style numerals in maths and you should include units as much as possible. Something like this looks a bit confusing to me:

[image: weird]

The `siunitx` package just makes it easier to be consistent:

```
In the experiment, shown schematically in figure 2.2, we illuminate an array of 10 slits,
each \SI{50}{nm} wide, with a laser beam at $\lambda = \SI{830}{nm}$.
```

[image: siunitx]

Now, this might also look inconsistent - first there is an old style 10, and then there is a lining 50. In these situations I prefer to just write 'ten' or not to use old style numerals at all.

Comment: Best answer so far, and most consistent.

Comment: This is exactly what I had decided to do, I'm glad someone else thinks the same way.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think using mathmode to write lining numbers in the text is the right approach. It only works properly if your math- and text font are identical.

If we follow Bringhurst's Elements of Typographical Style (and we should): "Use titling [lining] figures with full caps, and text [oldstyle] figures in all other circumstances" (p. 321).

So the recommendation is always to use oldstyle figures in text. I personally use:

- Proportional OSF in text
- Proportional Lining for math
- Proportional Lining fur full caps
- Monospaced OSF in tables

In order to achieve this you need a full font, e.g. Minion Pro, using the `MinionPro`package, or the now obsolete `libertine-legacy` package. It is also easy to set up with `fontspec` using XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX and an appropriate font.